# PHP HTTP Basic Auth using Form

Tags: php, http, authentication

How can I use HTTP basic Authentication and have the user submit their Username and Password in a HTML form and have it Authenticate using HTTP Basic Authentication.

I heard that Internet Explorer no longer supports the use of http://user:password@website.com no more so I don't know the best way to approach this.

Use of PHP and javascript and HTML is OK. I don't want to use PERL and I perfer no big javascript libs.

If you don't think HTTP Basic Auth. is the best way, please recommend something easy and simple to do. It will only be a login site for 5-6 people. No need to complicate it.

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be in an HTML form? Unless you use some sort of trickery like the `http://user:password@website.com` thing, HTTP Basic Authentication will cause the browser to display a standard popup box asking for the username and password. Would that be OK instead of an HTML form?

Comment: I want them to see an HTML form...submit it...and then have them login using HTML basic Auth... I dont want that popup box at all to show.

Comment: too much aesthetic for just logging in 5-6 people.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to combine HTTP Auth with a form. Use jQuery or XMLHttpRequest parameters as jcubic shows. The difficult part with that method is triggering a logout. That's why everyone recommends oldschool login forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery library has ajax function which has "password" and "user" parameter for Authentication. When user click login you can get value of login and password and passed to $.ajax function.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'authenticated.php',
      username: $('#login').val(),
      password: $('#passwd').val(),
      success: function(data) {
         //do something with data from the server
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the whole point of using HTTP authentication is being able to delegate authentication tasks:

1. The web server takes care of denying unauthorized access to protected resources
2. The browser takes care of asking for username and password when required

So you have a working system with minimum effort.

Now, if you use an HTML form to ask for credentials, the server will know who you are but the browser won't: it'll ask for credentials as soon as it finds the `WWW-Authenticate` response header and the `401` status code. For this to work, the browser has to send an `Authorization` request header on *every* HTTP request; however, your form cannot instruct the browser to send the appropriate HTTP header.

Of course, you can write your own server-side authentication code in PHP, configure the server to parse static files through it and omit `401` and `WWW-Authenticate` as soon as you get valid credentials (which then need to be stored somewhere else, e.g., a PHP session). But then you've lost all the advantages of HTTP authentication: at this point, a custom login handler with PHP sessions will be a much easier solution.

To sum up:

- If you need simplicity, forget about HTML forms
- If you need HTML forms, write your own code

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you need to use .htpasswd with .htaccess: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I already have the setup made. Currently they login with that ugly popup box. I'd rather have a styled form and have it pass to the site

Answer (score -1):

> How can I use HTTP basic Authentication and have the user submit their Username and Password in a HTML form

No way.

> please recommend something easy and simple to do.

sessions, cookies.
google for PHP auth tutorial and get over 9000 articles

oh well, one of them

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['auth_name'])) {
  $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['auth_name']);
  $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['auth_pass']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' AND pass='$pass'";
  $res = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
  if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit;
}
if (isset($_GET['action']) AND $_GET['action']=="logout") {
  session_start();
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/");
  exit;
}
if (isset($_REQUEST[session_name()])) session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) AND $_SESSION['ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) return;
else {
include 'your design here.php';
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="auth_name"><br>
<input type="password" name="auth_pass"><br>
<input type="submit"><br>
</form>
<? 
}
exit;
?>
```

intended to be put into file and called as `require '/path/auth.php';` at the top of your scripts